# iSCSI mounts in macOS

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra

I have a question about using iSCSI mounts in macOS (High Sierra). What is the preferred way to mount iSCSI targets in macOS? Also, is it possible to do so from Recovery Mode? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: iSCSI is not natively supported on macOS.  You need to use 3rd party software.  The best one that I have used (but it costs $$$) is the one from [globalSAN](http://www.studionetworksolutions.com/globalsan-iscsi-initiator/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free options are:
iSCSI Initiator for macOS
https://github.com/iscsi-osx/iSCSIInitiator

iSCSI Initiator X - Freemium
https://www.kernsafe.com/product/macos-iscsi-initiator.aspx

Answer (score 9):

[iSCSIInitiator](https://github.com/iscsi-osx/iSCSIInitiator/commits/master) has 0 commits since 2018, and [Kernsafe's product](https://www.kernsafe.com/product/macos-iscsi-initiator.aspx) has not seen an update since 11/2019. So both can effectively be considered abandonware at this point. Neither are working on Big Sur.

I found two options for Big Sur and newer:

- [Daemon Tools Lite for macOS](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/home#3Page/5). Performance seems to cap out around ~65MB/s (globalSAN was >100) but it seems stable and reliable so far.
- [ATTO Xtend SAN iSCSI Initiator](https://www.atto.com/xtend-san/) has recently been updated as well, and claims to support Big Sur/Monterey as well as Apple Silicon-based Macs. I haven't tested it.

Comment: Daemon tools does indeed work, but when the connection times out it simply drops (there is no persistence).  Anyone have a work around for this?

Comment: Related question: create iSCSI target LUNs on macOS… maybe someone knows how this would work on macOS. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460916/macos-as-server-os-possible-to-create-iscsi-target-luns

Comment: I've used both the GlobalSan licensed and a trial of Daemon tools, unfortunately on new Macs, GlobalSan is no longer supported.

My current dilemma is that I have Photos on a SynologyNas.  Every time I try to connect now it is asking me to initialise the drive which I believe will forma the LUN.

Does anyone know how to get access to the data?  I have tried connecting via various methods, Linux, Proxmox, MacOS old sierra and also new with daemon tools and Windows and none show the drive only an initialise message.